# Mono Develop unable to load plugins or editor

Tags: c#, monodevelop

When I load up MonoDevelop, it gives me an error, saying how it could not load the C# editor and plugins for my project. I have had this problem for as long as I can remember, and I can still use MonoDevelop to create scripts.

However, MonoDevelop no longer acts like an IDE, more like Notepad+. The lack of plugins causes MonoDevelop to lose even the most basic form of line suggestion. How do I fix this error, and restore the IDE capabilities of MonoDevelop?

---

> Could not load project 'Welp.CSharp.Plugins.csproj' with unknown item type '{E097FAD1-6243-4DAD-9C02-E9B9EFC3FFC1}'
>
> Could not load project 'Welp.CSharp.csproj' with unknown item type '{E097FAD1-6243-4DAD-9C02-E9B9EFC3FFC1}'
>
> Could not load project 'Welp.CSharp.Editor.csproj' with unknown item type '{E097FAD1-6243-4DAD-9C02-E9B9EFC3FFC1}'

Comment: What OS are you using? Have you recently (or not recently) moved any of the concerning folders or files?

Comment: I also wanted to address the edits I made to your post; Youl notice I have provided the error as text. Text errors are much more useful, as users can actually copy them to look up. I also removed your other image, as frankly, there was no point to it. ***We believe you***. You do not need to show us screen to confirm that this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is not the first time someone has raised an issue with an IDE reporting "unknown type '{E097FAD1-6243-4DAD-9C02-E9B9EFC3FFC1}'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086755/unityvs-visual-studio-can-not-open).

---

There are multiple answers, and they all seem to arrive at the same consensus: To fix this problem, *and actually re-enable the IDE functionality*, you should reinstall the software. This seems to be the only solution that has resulted in the IDE functionality resuming, and also covers the solutions for other potential causes:

- Some users have been able to simple "repair" their original installation; others have not. If the option is available, it is certainly worth the try.
- The problem may be caused by incorrectly installed .NET frameworks.
- The IDE might have a *differant* issue, where it *thinks* it can not support your project.
- The problem may be caused by an inconsistency in the .proj file, but feedback suggests that manually fixing this error *will not* resume IDE functionality. *If you want to try*, the suggestion is to remove `"<ProjectTypeGuids></ProjectTypeGuids>"`.

If you try this option, make sure you back up your projects, first. It might also be a good idea to double check the *version* of Unity you are using, if you do not automatically update. Older versions of the software are available from the website, if you do not wish to download the latest release.

---

It is worth noting that in the previously linked question, the top answer addresses this error as a result of *piracy*. This is *very unlikely*, especially in this case, given that MonoDevelop is a *free* IDE, and provided alongside Unity.